# sort an array of array objects by calculating the sum of key value by pairing it by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, highcharts, lodash

I have an array of objects

```
[{
    "data": [{
        "name": "John",
        "id": 1,
        "total": 5
    }, {
        "name": "Bob",
        "id": 2,
        "total": 7
    }],
    "location": "CA"
}, {
    "data": [{
        "name": "John",
        "id": 1,
        "total": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Matt",
        "id": 3,
        "total": 9
    }],
    "location": "NY"
}]
```

And I am trying to sort it by calculating the sum of "total" value by pairing it key "id" in lodash or javascript. This data is given to the highcharts for stacked column. I tried by applying groupBy, sortBy and all the examples I see are using only array and not array of arrays.

The resulting array I am expecting it to be

```
[{
    "data": [{
        "name": "Bob",
        "id": 2,
        "total": 7
    },{
        "name": "John",
        "id": 1,
        "total": 5
    }],
    "location": "CA"
}, {
    "data": [{
        "name": "Matt",
        "id": 3,
        "total": 9
    },{
        "name": "John",
        "id": 1,
        "total": 1
    }, ],
    "location": "NY"
}]
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look here on 
steps on how to ask good questions and get meaningful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please add what you want to sort and in which order.

Comment: I guess I'm confused by the question, because you say *"sort it by calculating the sum of "total" value by key "id" "*, but your expected resulting array (personally) doesn't make it clear how you mean to use the id in the sorting logic.

Comment: so... break your problem apart. It's pretty easy to find a QA pair for how to sum values in an array of objects, and it's also pretty easy to find a QA pair to sort an array... combine them.

Answer (score -2):

One way to tackle this would be using vanilla Javascript:

```js
const arr = [{
    "data": [{
        "name": "John",
        "id": 1,
        "total": 5
    }, {
        "name": "Bob",
        "id": 2,
        "total": 7
    }],
    "location": "CA"
}, {
    "data": [{
        "name": "John",
        "id": 1,
        "total": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Matt",
        "id": 3,
        "total": 9
    }],
    "location": "NY"
}];

arr.forEach(obj => {
  obj.data.sort((a,b) => b.total + b.id - a.total - a.id);
});

console.log(arr);
```